# Countif in R programming

Tags: r, countif, group

i have a data frame with the following columns

| Vendor | Product | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 1001 | 1.50 |
| 101 | 1001 | 1.50 |
| 101 | 1001 | 1.80 |
| 102 | 1001 | 2.10 |
| 102 | 1001 | 2.10 |
| 101 | 1002 | 10.10 |
| 101 | 1002 | 10.10 |
| 101 | 1002 | 10.10 |
| 103 | 1002 | 10.10 |
| 104 | 1002 | 20.10 |
| 104 | 1002 | 20.10 |
| 104 | 1002 | 10.10 |

i need to count how many times each price shows up for each product by each vendor and create a new dataframe df2 like the following:

| Product | Vendor | Price | count of Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 101 | 1.5 | 2 |
| 1001 | 101 | 1.8 | 1 |
| 1001 | 102 | 2.1 | 2 |
| 1002 | 101 | 10.10 | 3 |
| 1002 | 103 | 10.10 | 1 |
| 1002 | 104 | 10.10 | 1 |
| 1002 | 104 | 20.10 | 2 |

i am new in R programming and everything i tried so far is not working. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generating fake data:

```
vendor <- sample(x = 1:5,size = 100,replace = TRUE)+100  
product <- sample(x = 1:8,size = 100,replace = TRUE)+1000  
price <- (product-1000) + sample(x = -8:8,size = 100,replace = TRUE)/10  
df <- data.frame(vendor,product,price)
```

Solution with dplyr :

```
library(dplyr)  
df %>% group_by(vendor,product,price) %>% count %>% ungroup
```

Result :

```
# A tibble: 88 x 4
   vendor product price     n
    <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <int>
 1    101    1001   0.4     1
 2    101    1001   0.8     1
 3    101    1001   1       1
 4    101    1001   1.5     1
 5    101    1001   1.7     2
 6    101    1002   1.2     1
 7    101    1002   1.4     2
 8    101    1004   3.5     1
 9    101    1004   3.8     1
10    101    1004   3.9     2
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably a duplicated question

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%  
  count(Product, Vendor, Price, name = "Count")

# A tibble: 7 × 4
  Product Vendor Price Count
    <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <int>
1    1001    101   1.5     2
2    1001    101   1.8     1
3    1001    102   2.1     2
4    1002    101  10.1     3
5    1002    103  10.1     1
6    1002    104  10.1     1
7    1002    104  20.1     2
```

Answer (score 0):

This is again a duplicated question so the answer is as well!
I think `n()` the current group size is something that you are looking for, i.e.,

```
df <- read.csv(file='sof.csv') # df, your data
library(dplyr)
df %>% # df, your data
group_by(Product, Vendor, Price) %>%
summarise(`count of Price` = n())
?n() # n() gives the current group size
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `aggregate` like below

```
> aggregate(cnt ~ ., cbind(df, cnt = 1), sum)
  Vendor Product Price cnt
1    101    1001   1.5   2
2    101    1001   1.8   1
3    102    1001   2.1   2
4    101    1002  10.1   3
5    103    1002  10.1   1
6    104    1002  10.1   1
7    104    1002  20.1   2
```